# Get ID of a clicked row from an AJAX generated table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

When I click on the link with id="arriving" I call an AJAX function which interrogate a mysql database via arrivedInbox.php. arrivedInbox.php returns an array of data. 
I fill a table #inboxdashboard (created in the same document in the HTML part) with tr created dinamycally.
This is how I created the table:

```
<table id="inboxdashboard" style="display:none">
<tr id="myheadermob">
<td id="firstheadermob">Object</td>
<td id="secondheadermob">From</td>
<td id="thirdheadermob">Date</td>
</tr>
</table>


$('#arriving').click(function()
{   
     var str ="";
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "arrivedInbox.php",
                dataType:"json", 
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var arrayLength = data.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i=i+6) 
                    {
                        str ="";
                        str+="<tr class='trmessage' id=" + data[i+5] + ">";
                        str+="<td id='firstcolumnmob'>"+(data[i+3])+"</td>";
                        str+="<td id='secondcolumnmob'>"+(data[i+2])+"</td>";
                        str+="<td id='thirdcolumnmob'>"+(data[i+4])+"</td>";
                        str+="</tr>";
                        $('#inboxdashboard').append(str);
                    }
                    $("#inboxdashboard").show();

                }
            });
});
```

Everything works fine, I see the table with all the data in the right place. But what i'm trying to achieve is this:
Everytime I click on a tr of the  #inboxdashboard table i'd like to see an alert that display the id of the row I clicked on.

I tried this, but I failed:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{      
      $("#inboxdashboard tr").on("click", function() {
      alert("ID:  " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Note: If I create the rows in the HTML everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{      
      $("#inboxdashboard").on("click","tr", function() {
      alert("ID:  " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Another way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
}).on('click','#inboxdashboard tr',function(){
  // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your click function is missing a squig brace:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{      
      $("#inboxdashboard tr").on("click", function() {
        alert("ID:  " + $(this).attr('id'))
      };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The rows don't exist when the document is first ready, so you can't attach the event to their selector. Attach it to the document, and then *filter* by selector.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{      
   $(document).on('click', '#inboxdashboard tr', function() {
      alert("ID:  " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This will handle click events for rows that show up dynamically.